# Redirecting If logged in PHP

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication, steam

I have a website and i have a cover page that suggests the user logs in or registers, there is also a button to let them go to the site anyway. But i want it to detect if the user is actually logged in or not so that when they are logged in it will bypass the cover page and go to the home page.

Is there a way i can do this with PHP?

i currently just have the following code in my main page.

```
           <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
        steamlogin();
        }  else {
            include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');

          echo "Welcome back " . $steamprofile['personaname'] . "</br>";
          echo "here is your avatar: </br>" . '<img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title="" alt="" />';

          logoutbutton();
        }    
        ?>
```

Comment: Check if the $_SESSION['steamid'] is set on the cover page and direct them straight to the homepage....

Comment: Do you not already have that in your `else` statement?

Comment: It seems your code is correct. Whats the error you are facing now?

Comment: `header('Location:wherever_you_want_to_redirect.php');`

Comment: There is nothing to redirect in the code, it just displays the info and logout button on the cover page. What can i use to redirect to home.php for example

Comment: So you are just looking for `header('location: home.php');`?

Comment: Yeah, that is what im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did looks good, just some changes:

```
<?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
            steamlogin();
        }  else {
            header('Location: loggedUserPage.php'); 
           //It's better to redirect the user to a different page on this scenarios
        }   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i would do, or something like this.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) AND $_SESSION['steamid'] != '') {
    //user is logged in 
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    // not logged in
    header("location: login.php"); // or  steamlogin();
}
```